# Listening event in client side zeromq - node.js

Tags: node.js, filestream, zeromq

I am using [zeromq](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node) in the web analytics to have a real time notification of log.

**Details:**
    I am reading the log file (web analytics log file). Whenever the log file modified,it is to be read. It is same as the [tail](http://www.techonthenet.com/unix/basic/tail.php) in ubuntu. I am using zeromq for pub-sub event.

**sample server side:**

```
        var zmq = require('zmq');
        var socket = zmq.socket('pub');
        socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:2001', function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        var fs = require("fs");
        fs.watchFile(config.filePath, function (curr, prev) {
            socket.send("file updated");
        });

        var socket = zmq.socket('sub');//Have to be ported to client side
        socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:2001');
        socket.subscribe('');

        socket.on('message', function(msg){
              console.log('work: %s', msg);
        });
    });
```

**My question is** how to listen the event in the client side (javascript) and how to require zmq in client side?

I am new to zeromq. Any help will be greatful.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of client examples in node.js here...
https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/Node.js

Why do you have subscriber code on the server? Is this just a sanity check?

```
  var socket = zmq.socket('sub');
  socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:2001');
  socket.subscribe('');
  socket.on('message', function(msg){
       console.log('work: %s', msg);
  });
```

Comment: I had subscriber in server for testing. becoz i don't know to subscriber in client side. I had seen the examples in the above link. My doubt is how to require zmq in client side.

Comment: I followed that link you gave me and found that the examples I had previously been working on were incorrectly formed. The examples from the link you provided hit the spot and worked immediately! I posted my experience as an answer here.

Comment: Nice, glad to see contribution back to community :-D

Answer (score 1):

This may not relate to your question, but I figured I would add this in case anyone else is having issues getting the examples from ØMQ or the zguide.

If you are running a server-client example from this page (or a similar example set from the language of your choice):

http://zguide.zeromq.org/js:_start

and it's not working, then try checking out this page:

https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples

and try one of the examples in the language of your choice. This helped me immensely and the examples (so far) have worked on the first attempt!